# How do I make autocomplete data dynamic?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        onAutocomplete: function () {
            var mobileSearch = $('#SearchM').val();
            var desktopSearch = $('#SearchD').val();

            if (desktopSearch.length > 0){ //Desktop Search
                window.location.href = '/'+desktopSearch;
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/'+mobileSearch;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to get the data from the database and print it here. It's nonsense to write by hand when you have 5000+ data.

```
data: {
    "Apple": null,
    "Microsoft": null,
    "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
},
```

I was able to pull the data from an address with Fetch, but I couldn't print it.

```
var x = fetch('/alltags')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
```

What can I do ?

Comment: What do you mean you coudnt print it. Check your console, what is your response.

Comment: I mean, I couldn't print in autocomplete data: {}. I can display it on the console.

Answer (score 0):

The [JQuery Autocomplete Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) expects a [source property](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete#option-source), containing the options to display.

`source` accepts either an `Array`, `String` or `Function`.

You could map the response from your fetch into an array of objects.

> The `source` array can include strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
>
> *OR*
>
> Objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

*For example:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: [{
            label: "Google",
            value: "https://placehold.it/250x250"
        } ...],
        onAutocomplete: function () {
            var mobileSearch = $('#SearchM').val();
            var desktopSearch = $('#SearchD').val();

            if (desktopSearch.length > 0){ //Desktop Search
                window.location.href = '/'+desktopSearch;
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/'+mobileSearch;
            }
        }
    });
});
```